configure policy-enforcer to avoid intercepting public urls in keycloak and spring boot
We created a client resource server in keycloak and policies, permissions, scopes for resources, which works well, policy enforcer is used but the only problem that intercepts all requests (endpoint) backend including the public url which restricts and prevents access, we are new to this issue
if anyone can help in indicating how to solve the problem thank you in advance.
this is the file policy-enforcer.json:
{
  "realm": "online",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8182",
  "resource": "client-b",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "secret"
  }
}

this is the following code:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    String jwkSetUri;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                                 .requestMatchers("/public/*").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .addFilterAfter(createPolicyEnforcerFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter createPolicyEnforcerFilter() {
        PolicyEnforcerConfig config;

        try {
            config = JsonSerialization.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/policy-enforcer.json"), PolicyEnforcerConfig.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return new ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter(new ConfigurationResolver() {
            @Override
            public PolicyEnforcerConfig resolve(HttpRequest request) {
                return config;
            }
        });
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri).build();
    }

}

The routes were added manually in the file policy-enforcer.json following the keycloak documentation, it was done so that the keycloak resource server only uses the determined urls excluding the public url but it did not work, it still restricts the public url.
{
  "realm": "online",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8182",
  "resource": "client-b",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "secret"
  }
  "enforcement-mode" : "ENFORCING",
  "paths": [
    {
      "path" : "/archive/*",
      "methods" : [
        {
          "method": "GET",
          "scopes" : ["urn:client-b:access"]
        }
      ]
    }
    {
      "path" : "/send/create",
      "methods" : [
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "scopes" : ["urn:client-b:send:create"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Taking access control decisions on the authorization server sucks

@ch4mp Thank you very much for your contribution, I read what you shared, then I must use the file policy-enforcer.json together the filter (ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter)? excuse the ignorance but we are new to keycloak. I omitted the filter addFilterAfter(createPolicyEnforcerFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class) and there if the public url works but I do not know if it is ideal or correct?

I don't use Keycloak policy enforcer for the reasons I shared in the linked post. Instead, I use Spring Security @PreAuthorize("...") as written in the same post...

if you avoid the use of policy-enforcer.json and the ervletPolicyEnforcerFilter if it works by leaving the following configuration @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
.requestMatchers("/public/*").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
)
.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
return http.build();
}

@ch4mpwithout disabling the authentication and authorization leaving as is, the configuration that was in keycloak, but to your knowledge and experience would still give a result not ideal or correct to apply it that way? I saw your tutorial of git servlet-resource-server there you apply keycloak as backend or I'm wrong? very good examples and thanks for the contribution to share them.

Yes, I frequently use Keycloak as an authorization server. From time to time, I use other OpenID Providers for that (mostly Auth0 or Cognito, depending on what my clients use). I just don't control access to resources in authorization servers because it is not their responsibilities (that's resource servers one). That's the second time I write it in this comments and I'm also very clear about that in the linked answer...

@ch4mpit is good to use the keycloak and all the Auth2,OpenId,JWT etc security means, but not to use it as a resource server and use policy-enforcer to protect the paths of our backend for example a backend made in spring boot . Better to protect the routes in the following way @PreAtuhorize("hasAutority('ADMIN') which provides greater security in terms of any modification that is made in the resource server in keycloak, that's what you refer to the link you shared with me why not use keycloak and its disadvantages?

Ok, so you don't have an idea of what OAuth2 is about and try to secure an application with it...

@ch4mp thanks for the information, it is very good and explained.
